# Carry a value from a hidden column in a table to a new page using checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, html-table

My problem is a bit more extensive than the title but I'll try to explain what I'm doing.

OK to start lets pretend I've go two tables:

Table name: hosts

```
+------------+---------+
| host       | hostid  |
+------------+---------+
| EXAMPLE 1  |  10010  |
| EXAMPLE 2  |  10011  |
| EXAMPLE 3  |  10012  |
| EXAMPLE 4  |  10013  | 
+------------+---------+
```

Table name: items

```
+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
| itemid  | itemname     | value   | hostid  |
+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
|  27037  | examplename1 | DATA 1  | 10010   |
|  27038  | examplename2 | DATA 2  | 10011   |
|  27039  | examplename3 | DATA 3  | 10012   | 
|  27040  | examplename4 | DATA 4  | 10013   |
|  27041  | examplename5 | DATA 5  | 10013   |
|  27042  | examplename6 | DATA 6  | 10013   |
|  27043  | examplename7 | DATA 7  | 10013   |
+---------+--------------+---------+---------+
```

Now I put these into a web page using the following code:

```
<?php
$host = 'This is entered by user previously'

$sql = "SELECT hosts.host, items.itemname, items.value
    FROM items
    LEFT JOIN hosts ON hosts.hostid = items.hostid
    WHERE hosts.host LIKE '$host'";

$Connect = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)
    or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

$Db = @mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $Connect)
    or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());

$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect)
    or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());

mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);


$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
print "<table width=1000px border=1>\n";

$cols = 0;
while ($get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
if($cols == 0)
{
  $cols = 1;
  print "<tr>";
  print "<th>Host</th>";
  print "<th>Item Name</th>";
  print "<th>Item Value</th>";
  print "<tr>\n";
}
print "<tr>\n";
foreach ($get_info as $field)
print "\t<td><font face=arial size=3/>$field</font></td>\n";
print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
?>
```

If the user had entered 'EXAMPLE 4' this would be the resulting table:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+
| Host       | Item Name    | Item Value |
+------------+--------------+------------+
| EXAMPLE 4  | examplename4 | DATA 4     | 
| EXAMPLE 4  | examplename5 | DATA 5     | 
| EXAMPLE 4  | examplename6 | DATA 6     | 
| EXAMPLE 4  | examplename7 | DATA 7     | 
+------------+--------------+------------+
```

I now need to adjust this so that the resulting table will be displayed with a check-box next to each row. I need these check-boxes to correspond to the 'itemid' of each row(which is not displayed in the table) so that when getting to the next page I would be able to set up variables from them. For example if I ticked 'DATA 4' and 'DATA 7' on the next page they would be part of an array with the values '27040' and '27043'.

Apologies if this is worded badly but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the process.

Comment: Use AJAX if you will not have a Submit button.

Comment: Are you just asking how to create the checkboxes? If so, really you just need to add the itemid column to the SELECT query and put it in the value attribute of your checkbox...

Comment: Instead of a foreach statement, echo each row fields on their own instead of looping through them because the 4th field(the checkbox) is different to the others. Or if you really want to reduce code, loop foreach till the 3rd field then stop. Then echo the fourth element on its own with the <input type="checkbox" name="{$field}" value="{$field}" /> .

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways of doing this.

One simple way is to use the item ID when naming the checkboxes, that way you can get the needed value of the checkbox itself when you trigger the corresponding event to submit the information.

Another one would be hidden inputs named in a similar way as the corresponding checkbox (i.e checkbox ID= 'c_1' , hidden input id= 'h_1', where the hidden input has value='item_id')